# How do I make an ImageView optional in Android layout given that the source URL of the image may or may not exist?

Tags: android, mvvm, imageview, picasso, android-glide

In one of my Android layouts, one of the ImageView is "optional", meaning there isn't always a url for the src. I'm following the MVVM pattern, and I want to show the ImageView if there is a URL, and not show it if the URL is null.

First of all, I know this can be done using two separate, almost identical layout resource files. But I don't want to write that much code, especially since the only difference between these two layouts, is the fact that this thumbnail image may or may not exist (is null).

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_topic_creator_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::getProfileOfCurrentTopicCreator}"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_topic_body"
        app:userThumbnailUrl="@{viewModel.currentTopic.creator.thumbnailUrl}" />
```

And here is the code from the ViewModel:

```
    // circular image
@BindingAdapter({"userThumbnailUrl"})
public static void setUserThumbnailUrl(ImageView view, String url) {
    RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .circleCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.user_thumbnail_placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.user_thumbnail_placeholder)
            .priority(Priority.LOW);
    Glide.with(view.getContext())
            .load(url)
            .apply(options)
            .into(view);
}
```

In this case, `app:userThumbnailUrl` can't take in a null or empty string because that would cause an error in Glide. I can implement the logic in the ViewModel to check to see if the url is null or empty, then don't use Glide, but then what do I return as a result? Do I just not do anything when the url is null? Wouldn't that cause an error in the ImageView and cause things to crash in the app?

Comment: did you try to check if url is null then Hide the imageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ImageView` is by default visible. Have the default be invisible, and then show it if the url exists.

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_topic_creator_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:visible="gone" //set invisible here here
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::getProfileOfCurrentTopicCreator}"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_topic_body"
        app:userThumbnailUrl="@{viewModel.currentTopic.creator.thumbnailUrl}" />




@BindingAdapter({"userThumbnailUrl"})
    public static void setUserThumbnailUrl(ImageView view, String url) {

        if (url != "") {
            RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .circleCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.user_thumbnail_placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.user_thumbnail_placeholder)
                .priority(Priority.LOW);
            Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .apply(options)
                .into(view);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
        // circular image
@BindingAdapter({"userThumbnailUrl"})
public static void setUserThumbnailUrl(ImageView view, String url) {
    RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .circleCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.user_thumbnail_placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.user_thumbnail_placeholder)
            .priority(Priority.LOW);
    if(url != null && !url.isEmpty() ){ 
        Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .apply(options)
                .into(view);
    } else{
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```